# Macro to start at a particular time

Tags: vba, excel

I have found sources that say to use

```
Application.OnTime TimeValue("18:00:00"), "MyMacro"
```

But I can't seem to get it to work. This is what I have entered

```
Sub TimeStamp()
'
' TimeStamp Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+T
'
  Application.OnTime TimeValue("13:25:00"), "TimeStamp"

' Following refreshes the data
    Application.CalculateFullRebuild
```

Then the rest of the code followed by `End Sub`

For whatever unknown reason, when I start the Macro, it does not wait until that given time. What syntax rules am I breaking here?

Comment: Put "Option Explicit" at the very top of your code.  That might help you pin it down,

Comment: I would stick with Chip's suggestion and create a separate procedure for the timer.

Comment: @findwindow I am going to use chip's suggestion to repeat the process ever 15 minutes. This part I need to get the Macro to start when the stock exchange opens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro is triggered when the macro is triggered. OnTime schedules it to be run automatically, but why should that prevent you from running it manually? Think of it like a virus scan. Many people have their computers configured to do automatic scans at certain set times, but are perfectly able to run nonscheduled scans at any time. If you want to make sure that your macro doesn't have any effect before a certain time, use an if - then statement involving Now (if it is too early exit sub) -- although it makes more sense to not run it at all when you don't want to.

Comment: oh that makes sense. So I don't even have to press anything to let it know to start. It just starts when the time comes. Okay perfect.

Comment: @THATnewbie If you are relying on the sub to schedule itself then you would need to manually run it at least once since otherwise the line which sets the schedule wouldn't be executed. Think about the virus scan situation -- you still need to run the set-up software at least once even if you want to just have it run automatically in the future. If you don't want the sub to really do anything the first time you run it, the logic could be tricky. Hence I endorse the idea that others have mentioned of writing a different sub to schedule the first.

Answer (score 1):

Another method that I've used for years successfully is by just creating a small vb script that is scheduled to call the macro.  My other answer to a very similar question show this example script

```
Dim xlApp
Dim xlWkb
Set xlApp = CreateObject("excel.application")
Set xlWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("PATH TO YOUR FILE")
xlApp.Visible = True
xlWkb.RunAutoMacros 1 'enables macros to be run on open
xlApp.Run ("YOUR PROCEDURE")
xlApp.Workbooks("YOUR WORKBOOK NAME").Save 'Save the workbook
xlApp.Quit 'quits excel
```

Schedule this through Tasks Scheduler.  My other answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293802/is-it-possible-to-run-macro-only-when-excel-file-is-opened-by-task-scheduler/27298675#27298675/%22here%22)

Comment: I use a similar method but use the auto_open sub name in the code to fire off the macro, then I just schedule excel.exe with the workbook as a parameter. I do prefer both yours and my method over a timer where the sheet needs to be left open, any issue or lockup and it basically dies, with a scheduled task it will simply fire off again 15 mins later.

Comment: Nice. I can definitely see the advantage of not needing to keep the Application object in memory just so it can fire macros on time.

Comment: @DanDonoghue at my old emplyer we had a workbook with some subs that would makes calls to literally hundreds of other macros in the workbook to process files that were emailed into our IT email acct.  This particular one ran every 30 minutes to process flat files to upload into our custom software.  I can say from expeirence this is a very reliable method.  If it ever error ever occured an automated email would be sent to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with thanks to the help of several of you. I used:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.Wait "6:45:00"
Call TimeStamp
End Sub
```

and placed this in "ThisWorkbook". This made it so that when I open up my workbook, the macro is automatically started but it waits until 3:03 pm to perform the rest of the task.

Next, I needed it to refresh every 15 minutes so I used [Chip's](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/OnTime.aspx) solution suggested by User: Findwindow. The code goes as follows

```
Public RunWhen As Double
Public Const cRunIntervalSeconds = 900 ' 15 minutes
Public Const cRunWhat = "TimeStamp"  ' the name of the procedure to run

Sub StartTimer()
    If Time < TimeSerial(13, 15, 0) Then

    RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, cRunIntervalSeconds)
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, _
        Schedule:=True
    End If
End Sub
```

at the end of the TimeStamp macro, I put `Call StartTimer` so that every time the macro is ran, the timer will schedule a new run time for 15 minutes from the current time. The `If Time < TimeSerial(13, 15, 0) Then` allows for the macro to stop running at 1:15pm, the time that I wanted it to stop.

Comment: Thanks to @Findwindow for the help